# Laravel filament: Is there any way to mutate group data column default value in table?

Tags: laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have a user model. I grouped data by `user_type`, now grouped data shows with default value of the column. How can it be formatted?

[image]

Is there any way to show `user_type` field formatted value on group in table?

Comment: Do you have a corresponding enum for the ```user_type``` column

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [docs](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/tables/grouping#setting-a-group-title) you can customize group title by using `getTitleFromRecordUsing`

```
public function table(Table $table): Table
{
    return $table
        ->groups([
            Group::make('user_type')
                ->getTitleFromRecordUsing(function ($record) {
                    $value = (int) $record->user_type;
                    return match ($value) {
                        1 => "User",
                        2 => "Admin",
                        default => "Unknown"
                    };
                }),
        ]);
}
```